# What is $get in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I haven't been able to find documentation in AngularJS docs on use-cases of `$get`. I'm trying to understand where and how to use it.

Below is an example from the AngularJS docs

```
function GoodProvider() {
  this.$get = angular.noop;
}
```

Does this attach `angular.noop` to the `GoodProvider` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it attaches noop.

Look at the documentation on Providers, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

"The Provider recipe is syntactically defined as a custom type that implements a $get method. This method is a factory function just like the one we use in the Factory recipe. In fact, if you define a Factory recipe, an empty Provider type with the $get method set to your factory function is automatically created under the hood."

Comment: From the docs, `The Provider recipe is syntactically defined as a custom type that implements a $get method.` - its similar to an HTTP method GET?

Comment: The $get method is the factory function for creating the service. It is not the same as the $http method.

Comment: Here is a link that explains the factory method pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.